How to prick Black Eyed Susan?
I recently received black eyed susan seeds and a biodegradable pot as a present.
Now they are seedlings like this and I'm planning to replant them in a bigger pot. I'm a complete beginner I've never grown a plant before so I need some help.

How big should the pot be? Is a 20x20cm pot fine?
Should I pick out extras so that there's only one per pot or can I keep multiple sprouts in a pot?


Note that the general idea of "pricking out" small seedlings is to carefully extract them with roots to put into their own pot so you have more seedlings. Depending on seedling size a toothpick or  a slightly larger tool may be appropriate. "Thinning" would be just killing off the extras - your title says "prick" and your question uses "pick" in a manner that appears to imply thinning. You may want to [edit] to clarify which you mean.

Congrats on taking up gardening.   You might want to ensure you do actually want to gro Black-Eyed Susan - it is considered a weed in many places (ie once established can smother other plants and be difficult to eradicate).  Of-course, this may not be a problem with your variety/climate/use case - but its worth considering.
I would imagine that for Black Eyed Susan the size of the pot is not particularly important at this stage however as a general gardening you would normally transplant a plant to "the next size up" pot - eg something 1/3rd bigger.
You would normally have 1 sprout per pot, although I imagine having more then 1 won't hurt.  (If you are planting in a garden, the idea is to plant at least 30cm apart.   It might be an idea to take out 1 sprout and repot it, and leave the second sprout to grow more before repotting it - that probably buys you insurance and gives you the best of both worlds.
I've not done much with biodegradable pots, but the idea is that you simply grow the plant in them, and then plant the whole pot in the ground - it will biodegrade in the ground and not disturb the plant root system  (actually I imagine the plant root system will help break it down).

Note that it's a deer favorite.
